# Java Code Applet Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "MyFile.txt" "read")

Tags: java, io, applet, accesscontrolexception

I got the following error while i was trying to read a file and store it's data into my applet(Java)
i think that the main error is this :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (
     "java.io.FilePermission" "MyFile.txt" "read")
```

And I have no idea how to resolve it, thought it might something to add to my `java.policy.applet` file which include:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I also tried to google it but nothing works.

Comment: Don't use AllPermissions, that's a massive security hole. Applets run within a strict security sandbox, that's the point. Why are y using an applet to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments guys,

i have solved this problem by reading "MyFile.txt" as a URL, and then read it

the code:

```
        URL myURL = new URL("http://MyDomainName.com/MyFile.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream()));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    line.add(inputLine);
                in.close();
```

Solved

Comment: Safer and more portable to use something like `URL myURL = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "MyFile.txt");` ..glad you got it sorted. :)